# Is the complexity of 3 logn and 2logn same?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

DOes it have same complexity since they vary by constant multiplier, or should it be made n^3 and n^2 and be compared?

Comment: Multiplier doesn't matter

Answer (score 5):

For 'BigOh' notation, the constant multiplier really doesn't matter. All that it does is, it gives the order of the running time complexity.
You can consider this small example:
Say you have 3 * 100 = 300 apples and 2 * 100 = 200 apples. Surely, 300 != 200, but the order of both are same, that is in order of hundreds.

So by the same means, 3(log n) != 2(log n), but both 3(log n) and 2(log n) are in the order of log n, that is O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Multiplying by a constant doesn't matter. The are both just `O(log n)`.

In fact, this is part of the definition of big-o notation. If a function may be bounded by a polynomial in n, then as n tends to infinity, you may disregard lower-order terms of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent to O(log n). The constant does not alter the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

[Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is defined by the set of all upper bounded functions.

With that being said, it is also important to note that Big O can be defined mathematically as:

`O(g(n)) = {f(n): f(n) < c·g(n), c being some arbitrary constant}`

So as you can see, the constant doesn't really matter in Big O; we don't care if there *is* one that works. So both `3logn` and `2logn` both can be described as `O(logn)`.